# Is there a ROS package that can generate analog and digital output?

Tags: ros, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ROS to control a motor controller. But the motor controller can only be controlled by analog and digital input. Is there a ROS package that can do that?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50809/is-there-a-ros-package-that-can-generate-analog-and-digital-output?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my knowledge there are no I/O or gpio packages available. You could buy an arduino, this a microcontroller with a serial (over usb) interface on which you can perform analog and digital input and output. You can control it with the ros serial package I suggested before. Example of how to blink a led ( the led could also be the motor controller, with some extra components off course). http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-19**:
I currently use Gumstix Overo® FE COM computer-on-module and Gumstix RoboVero micro controller. Gumstix RoboVero micro controller is used to communicate with motor controllers. So there is no ROS package for Gumstix RoboVero and there is only package for Arduino, right?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-19**:
Is it hard to write a ROS package for RboVero micro controller?

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-12-19**:
If the robovero is running an embedded linux system, you may want the embeddedlinux version of rosserial instead http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_embeddedlinux.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-22**:
Hi JonW, I think Overo and its daughter board RoboVero can run Ubuntu and full ROS stacks. So it might not need to use embeddedlinux version of rosserial. The problem right now is that whether or not the rosserial package can be used on Gumstix RoboVero.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-22**:
And can rosserial package generate digital and analog signal on RoboVero daughter board.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-23**:
From a quick search on Google I found this information stating that it is possible: http://gumstix.8.n6.nabble.com/Advice-on-Overo-AirSTROM-COM-and-RoboVero-td4964450.html (second post, not sure which ros package is used..)

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-23**:
With the python code posted here, it would also be possible to create your own node
http://robovero.org/lab/projects/rainy-day-project-panning-webcam/